# What does the notation $2^{-\Omega(n)}$ mean in probability?

Tags: probability, computer-science, computational-complexity

When I read papers in theoretical computer science, I see the notation $probability<2^{-\Omega(n)}$ to denote the probability.

My queestion is

What Does $\Omega$ mean? Is it the same as in complexity theory?

Example1:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1211.7184.pdf . The last sentence of the Theorem 2.

Example2:

$1-e^{-1/3}-e^{-\Omega(n)}=\Omega(1)$.

page 40 in https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-16544-3

or you can see the last sencence in the picture.
[image]

Comment: Have you an example of such an occurrence?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation (See Big Omega Notation.)

Comment: That would almost certainly be the same big-omega as in complexity theory, yes. I was originally going to say that this could be more easily written as $o(2^{-n})$, but there are subtle differences between the two expressions; $o(2^{-n})$ can still be exponential diminution, but $2^{-\Omega(n)}$ is necessarily superexponential in its decline.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut  Thanks for your remind, I added two examples.

Comment: @QiZhu Thanks for your link, but there is few things about probability.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki. Thanks for your comment. Could you please explain the second example?